# Count every word in a text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

What i want is to be able to feed in a multiline Text file which is like a paragraph long and then to be returned with something like:

```
{'Total words': 'NUMBER', 'Words ending with LY': 'NUMBER'}
```

I have never used Counter before but i believe that is how i would do it. So i want it to count every word and if the word ends in LY add it to the second count. Considering i have never used Counter i don't know where to go...

```
with open('SOMETHING.txt') as f:
  # something to do with counter here?
```

EDIT: I have to do it without using counter! how would i achieve the same result but without the counter library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you...

```
def parse_file():
  with open('SOMETHING.txt', 'r') as f:
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    for i in f:
      w = i.split()
      c1 += len(w)
      for j in w:
        if j.endswith('LY'):
          c2 += 1
    return {'Total words': c1, 'Words ending with LY': c2}
```

I would recommend however, you have a look at [a few python basics](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: have at it. Feel free :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this hard to try?

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
result_second = defaultdict(int)
for word in open('text.txt').read().split():
    result[word] += 1
    if word.endswith('LY'): 
        result_second[word] +=1
print result,result_second
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'and': 1, 'Considering': 1, 'have': 2, "don't": 1, 'is': 1, 'it': 2, 'second': 1, 'want': 1, 'in': 1, 'before': 1, 'would': 1, 'to': 3, 'count.': 1, 'go...': 1, 'how': 1, 'add': 1, 'if': 1, 'LY': 1, 'it.': 1, 'do': 1, 'ends': 1, 'used': 2, 'that': 1, 'I': 1, 'Counter': 2, 'but': 1, 'So': 1, 'know': 1, 'never': 2, 'believe': 1, 'count': 1, 'word': 2, 'i': 5, 'every': 1, 'the': 2, 'where': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use collections.Counter()

```
import collections

with open('your_file.txt') as fp:
    text = fp.read()
    counter = collections.Counter(['ends_in_ly' if token.endswith('LY') else 'doesnt_end_in_ly' for token in text.split()])
```

Without counter

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    tokens = fp.read().split()
    c = sum([1 if token.endswith('LY') else 0 for token in tokens])
    return {'ending_in_ly': c, 'not_ending_in_ly': len(tokens) - c}
```

Comment: I've added a solution without counter.

Comment: Careful, read() will load the entire file into memory. If the file is large, you may exhaust the system's RAM memory.